# Keep part of page from rendering till input is given

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react and was wondering if its possible to render part of a page after the user submits the input. The issue is I'm trying to merge two pages and am using struts to create select fields. The select fields on the page I'm loading are dependent on the input from the first page. Is it possible to hide and render the last half of the page after the input is given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `state` or `props` for rendering a section of your page conditionally, something like this:

```
{this.state.input &&
        <div> 
          other tags.......
        </div>
        }
```

the `input` state is updated by changing the value in the first page's input.

Comment: Good answer, though personally I'd opt to explicitly check for an empty string, just for clarity, like `this.state.input !== ''` or `this.state.input.length > 0`